# angular js - stop displaying images once overflow is reached

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fileresult

I have a bunch of images that im serving up (from an external source im hosting elsewhere) onto a page via an mvc fileresult and into an angular ng-src.

eg.

```
<div ng=repeat="img in Images">
        <img ng-src={{img.path}} style="height:100px;width:auto" />
</div>`
```

In this case I know that the img.path is always going to the external c# mvc and returning a filestream to the content.

I wish to only fit a certain 'summed' width of images on the screen - so that i do not have images half showing such as if i were to use "overflow:hidden" in a parent div.

Is there a way I can set ng-repeat to continue until the next image would overflow ( and thus preventing the overflow altogether) ? The images are being resized so that their height is all set to 100px, and the width proportionally scaling to meet this size. 
`

I thought the below directive would do the trick but it seems to rescale the images for some reason..

```
App.directive('styleParent', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
            elem.on('load', function () {
                var w = $(this).width(),
                    h = $(this).height();

                var xPos = angular.element(this).prop('offsetLeft');
                xPos += w;

                var div = elem.parent();
                var d_width = div.width();
                var d_xPos = angular.element(div).prop('offsetLeft');
                d_xPos += d_width;

                console.log([xPos, d_xPos, this])
                if (xPos > d_xPos) {
                    angular.element(this).hide();
                }


            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to nest the image inside another div, test the image position against the original div as earlier and then hide the images parent div as opposed to the image itself.